How to prevent MacBook from going to sleep when running tasks?
I'm running some python scripts for many hours and my MacBook Pro Keeps trying to go to sleep (I think). I am not sure if going to sleep is the proper term. Essentially what happens is that after a while it tries to close all the apps that are running and brings me back to a locked screen. Most of the time it doesn't manage to close some Chrome windows and I come back to this message:

(In french: "Leave website? Your modifications might not be saved.")
However, even though it doesn't manage to close down everything, it does manage to close down some windows that are relevant to me i.e. my python script.
I've been leaving it for the night to run, and always to come back to it unsuccessfully having tried to go to sleep. I've caught it doing that on a couple of occasions, and it is really frustrating, but I cannot figure out why it is trying to log out. Not only that, but I've experienced this in the past too while playing music from Apple Music - the computer would just shut down all the apps it can, and lock the screen. It seems it is unable to shut down certain apps that ask you if you want to save your work or if you really want to quit. All of this also kept happening on a 2016 MacBook Pro I used to have. It never happens if I am actively using the computer.
My specs are:
MacBook Pro (14 inches, no. 2023)
M3 Pro Chip
18 Go
Sonoma 14.4.1
And my settings for locking the screen are all on "Never", so are my settings for battery mode and screen saver.
I'm trying to run caffeinate right now to see if that fixes the problem, will probably have to check back on it tomorrow morning since I will be using the computer during the day.
Thanks in advance for any help!

in the Control Panel, in Privacy and Security, go to Advanced.
One of the options there is 'log out automatically after inactivity'. It sounds like that is enabled on your system.

Yup, sleep alone shouldn't be trying to close anything.

To supplement @Hobbes' answer, for those who prefer Terminal commands:
enable logout (after 20m)
MINS=20 ; SECS=$(( MINS * 60 ))
for k in autologout.AutoLogOutDelay securitypref.logoutvalue ; do
  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.$k -int $SECS
done

disable auto-logout
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay -int 0
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.securitypref.logoutvalue

